# How to join each individual file in list with another data frame in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, join, merge

I have created a list of 500 files from CSVs and appended a column with their file name using the following code:

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
file_list <- lapply(filenames, function(x) cbind(Ticker_Symbol=strsplit(x,'\\.')[[1]][1], read.csv(x)))
```

Each file is similarly structured, but the row numbers and column names are not identical across all of them.

I have another data frame with the "Ticker_Symbol" column, and I'd like to join each file with this other data frame. I would then like to merge all of the files into a single data frame.

Snippet of each file ("Date" column improperly refers to elements of income statement):

```
Ticker_Symbol     Date      2020-12     2020-09     2020-06
     ZTS       Net Income    1.20B       1.1B       1.097B
```

Snippet of data frame to be joined with:

```
Ticker_Symbol    Date      Close
    ZTS         2020-12    11.8
```

The steps I need to take in order are the following:

1. Transpose each of the 500 lists other than the ticker_symbol column (dates as rows, the income statement elements under the "date" column as columns)
2. Join each file in list with the other data frame to add the "Close" column
3. Merge the list into one data frame

I've been working on this for a while, and have run into a few problems:

1. I can't figure out how to transpose the elements of the list without first merging them into a single data frame.
2. I can't figure out how to join the elements of the list with another data frame without first merging them.
3. When I do merge all of the lists, I get a separate "Ticker_Symbol" column for each ticker ("Ticker_Symbol.x" for "AAPL", "Ticker_Symbol.y" for "ABBV", etc.) I need all the Ticker_Symbols to be in a single column after merging. This is the code I'm running to merge:

```
merged_table <- Reduce(function(x, y) full_join(x, y, by="Date"), file_list)
```

Ideal output should look something like this:

```
Ticker_Symbol       Date      Net_Income      Close
    ZTS           2020-12        1.20B         11.8
    ZTS           2020-09        1.1B          11.6
    ZTS           2020-06        1.097B        11.5
    AME           2020-12        600M          10.8
    AME           2020-09        689.4M        10.9
    AME           2020-06        702.8M        11.2
```

Sorry for the lengthy question - new to R, and I've been trying unsuccessfully to figure out this problem for almost a week now. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you don't need a join but `cbind`. Try : `merged_table <- do.call(cbind, file_list)`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue with joining the tables, I think `merge()` does what you need. It either merges two tables `x` and `y` on common column names or on columns specified explicitely with the parameters `by`, `by.x` or `by.y`. Have a look at `?merge` for a full description. You can also specify suffixes appended to common column names not used for merging.

Your table with the `Net Income` data seems to be a different problem, as it appears to be a mixture of wide and long format, while mixing up column names and data fields. I think fixing a datastructure like this in R will get a little ugly. If possible, it will probably be easier to fix this outside of R by using something like `awk`.

If you need to do it in `R` I would try to read the data in as a list and try to reorganize it into a data structure suitable for a data.frame, as this is the interface expected by most of the data analysis functions.